# How to calculate the Likelihood function of a gaussian pdf

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, estimation, data-analysis, particle-detectors

Suppose a **model** for a **flux** of (astro)particles $\dot \Phi(E,t)$ (from a supernovae) that depends on particle energy $E$ and time $t$ (from beginning of explosion), and 3 free parameters $T_a, M_a, \tau_a$ (in which, for simplicity I won't show the details).

I have $\approx 20$ events from detection in which I have the particle energy $E$ (and corresponding relative time $t$ from first event).

To  estimate the best fit for the $T_a, M_a, \tau_a$ I have guessed a gaussian p.d.f. and tried to plot the Likelihood function $L$

$$L = \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{- (x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} .$$

My question is: once I have only energy and time, what should I use as $x_i$ (data) and $\mu$ $(\sigma)$ to estimate best fit values of $T_a, M_a, \tau_a$?

Comment: Well, the data are the data, so the $x_i$ should be the measured energy and time values. But to assess whether your likelihood is reasonable and to describe the other parts of the likelihood, you need to specify (a) some theoretical model that lets you predict observed data from the theoretical parameters and (b) some probabilistic model of the noise in your experiment (ie the probability of finding a particular noise realization).

Comment: In a particle detection experiment, the number of observed events is typically a random number drawn from a Poisson distribution whose mean value is mu. Then, the equation that relates the flux and the three model parameters is needed to determine mu. The conversion from flux to the mu can be done using the acceptance of the detector.